# unity camera follow rolling box

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

i have a cube that rolls with the arrow keys or control pad
up goes up, left turns left, and right turns right, so only the up makes it roll
im trying to get a camera to follow but not really getting anywhere
i found this script cant rember where that im trying to alter
but as i roll the cube forward the camera spins
simple video showing movment
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPsiF.jpg
any pointers in the right direction sorry about the pun would be good
           simple lookat script

```
      public Transform player;

 void Start()
 {

}


void Update()
{
    Vector3 targetPostion = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x,     transform.position.y,player.transform.position.z);
    transform.LookAt(targetPostion);

 }
```

and the follow script

```
// The target we are following
public Transform target;
// The distance in the x-z plane to the target
//So this would be your offset
public float distance = 10.0f;
// the height we want the camera to be above the target
public float height = 5.0f;
// How much we 
public float heightDamping = 2.0f;
public float rotationDamping = 3.0f;

void LateUpdate()
{
    // Early out if we don't have a target
    if (!target) return;

    // Calculate the current rotation angles
    float wantedRotationAngle = target.eulerAngles.y;
    float wantedHeight = target.position.y + height;


    float currentRotationAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
    float currentHeight = transform.position.y;

    // Damp the rotation around the y-axis
    currentRotationAngle = Mathf.LerpAngle(currentRotationAngle, wantedRotationAngle, rotationDamping *     Time.deltaTime);

    // Damp the height
    currentHeight = Mathf.Lerp(currentHeight, wantedHeight, heightDamping * Time.deltaTime);

    // Convert the angle into a rotation
    var currentRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, currentRotationAngle, 0);

    // Set the position of the camera on the x-z plane to:
    // distance meters behind the target
    transform.position = target.position;
    transform.position -= currentRotation * Vector3.forward * distance;

    // Set the height of the camera
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, currentHeight, transform.position.z);

    // Always look at the target

    Vector3 thetargetPostition = new Vector3(0, target.position.y,0);
    transform.LookAt(target.position);
    //transform.LookAt(thetargetPostition);
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: What sort of motion of the camera are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Shingo sorry I’m trying to get the camera to follow the cube but only rotate around the up axis even thou the cube is rotating

Comment: Hi immersive I’m trying to get the camera to follow the cube and when it rotates not rolls slowly turn to follow thanks

Comment: So you want a 'chase' camera?

Comment: Hi yes immersive that’s right cheers